# What open databases with aircraft, airlines and country exist?

Tags: website, datasets

As the above question states, I'm looking for an open database that I can access. I'm building a plane spotter app, and need a lot of data.

The data needs to be downloaded.

Comment: Let's assemble our minions and build one! Haha. You might want to take a look at this: http://www.flightradar24.com/data/airplanes/
I'm not sure if they have an API for it though :)

Comment: That would be awesome! I kinda found somthing that I'm thinking about spidering. http://www.airfleets.net/recherche/country.htm Is it a good one? An API would not be enough.

Comment: I have spent the last couple of days to build a crawler for you, it is written in PHP, and is almost complete. For the moment: It stores all the data it crawls into a MySQL database table. If you want it stored im some other way: Let me know :)

Comment: Wow that's amazing! Currently working on it myself. I would love to take a look at it. MySQL database is perfect!

Comment: Add me on Skype so we can chat without filling up the comment section, I dont think the mods like it. My Skype is: djzorrow .
I have started to collect the data now, but with 23090 aircrafts: It takes quite some time.

Answer (score 5):

Geographic (routes, land-based infrastructure) data:

- http://ourairports.com/data/
- http://openflights.org/data.html

Coordination (scheduling, flight numbers) data:

- http://www.virtualradarserver.co.uk/FlightRoutes.aspx

Aircraft (registration) data:

- *List of national government registers* - http://www.gatwickaviationsociety.org.uk/registers_official.asp
- *ICAO address country prefixes* - http://www.kloth.net/radio/icao24alloc.php
- *(old) id and routing data* - http://www.libhomeradar.org/download/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen Flight Aware's [Flight Status API](http://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/)?

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great service, but it's a project for a friend so I need the data to be free. The app may not even go online so I'm not going to make any money of it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/54141)

Comment: @FreeMan In general you are right of course, but in this case the question is asking about an online database, so a link would IMHO be appropriate as an answer. The questions itself is however a resource location question and should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Agreed, @Bianfable, and I thought about that, I just didn't do it. I thought maybe the standards were different that long ago.